# Update Salesforce Web Reference

Tags: visual-studio-2010, salesforce

So I've added a custom field to a Salesforce Object and need to update the Web Reference and proxy classes created from said web reference.  What I'm doing is replacing the existing WSDL file in the Web Reference folder with the new Enterprise WSDL file.  I then right-click the Web Reference instance (in this case, SFDC) and select "Update Web Reference" however nothing happens.  In fact, the updated WSDL file reverts back to its original state and the proxy class file does change at all.

Am I missing a step here?

Answer (score 1):

I actually accomplished this by deleting the web reference, than creating a new one, which added the new field.